# gif.js returns a blob object. how to save it to SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, blob, gif

I've been working on using gif.js (http://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/) to create gifs on the site.
I realized gif.js returns the gif image in blob format.

in the demo is like:

```
gif.on('finished', function(blob) {
  window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
});
```

seems that the URL(`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`) it returns only lives on the browser memory which means the next time I open the page, the URL will be 404.

I'd like to save the gifs into database using mySQL, so I have a gif gallery to show.
I tried to console log and see the `blob`, it seems to be an object that contains the size(ex:12345) and type(ex:image/gif). I couldn't even find the image information.

[image]

How couldn't I save the gifs into database and be able to retrieve it to make a gallery?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Why not store files in a filesystem? It's a pretty standard and widely used solution

Comment: mySql is the only database language I've learned so far. I would prefer to use mySql this time. I will check filesystem out for future sites I make.

Comment: that's one of the most terrible justifications one explains the bad design decision I have seen ever. PS: "I've learned so far" --- if you have learned - you wouldn't have asked a trivial questions presumably ;-)

Comment: Just FYi, I am a student just started learning the back-end suff. if I know filesystem, I'll definitely use it. Since I've been building the site with mySql already, and I know it's doable, why not finish the project with the original plan? so at least I know I can write in mySql.

Comment: okay. So just write it. Any particular issue with that? It's exactly the same as you would write a string.

Comment: the blob it returns is an object (has type and size) not a string. Not sure where is the image information.

Comment: so the question is how to retrieve image information now? Or how to write binary data into database? `console.log(blob)` ?

Comment: I console.log(blob). shows 
Blob {type: "image/gif", size: 42678, slice: function}
size: 42678
type: "image/gif"
which is not a string. I have no idea how to turn it into binary data and put into DB. I just added a screenshot of the console

Comment: 1. google "javascript Blob" 2. the first link is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob 3. there is an example there. As a student you should have known that the documentation is the first place to get the information

Comment: I've visited the documentation page actually but still didn't find the answer. except type and size, I got nothing else on console.log(blob). I tried blob.slice(); and didn't get anything either :-(

Comment: "Example for extracting data from a Blob"

Comment: Thanks!! I looked into FileReader and tested out different functions. readAsDataURL returns "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhaAEcAvcAAAAAAP7lgP7lgP7lgP7lgP7lgP/mgf/mgf/mg…AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" looks promising!